# how to call stored value in a variable in a SSIS package

Tags: ssis

All,
I am very very new to SSIS development. So needed a help.
In one of my package, I have stored a result set in a variable(For example : Variable A) on one Execute SQL Task.

I need to do following on another Execute SQL Task on same package :

1. Truncate the Customer table (This table has only one column "Gender")
2. I want to insert the value of variable A to a column "Gender

So my SQL is something like this:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE Customer

INSERT INTO Customer
Gender 
Select Variable A
```

Can anyone please help me with this? also what how should I set up parameters for this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: `truncate table customer` is correct. What actual problem are you having with this? Why are you loading a resultset into a variable? why not just load it directly into the table? To get an answer for this you should give some more background and explain what you've tried

Comment: Thanks for the response.. I have used long query to get a result set. To avoid using the same long query again on the step down, I would like to just store the result in a variable and use that variable value to insert on that table.

Comment: Why do you need to 'use it again on the step down'? I don't see any reason to use a recordset

Comment: The pattern that works for me is to load a dataset into a staging table in to target database and use T-SQL to work on it. This is much faster than messsing with recordsets and SSIS code

Comment: But if you must load a recordset into a database, you need to use a For Each ADO enumerator to step through each record. The inside you use an execute SQL task to insert a row. Here's something similar but you need to use an Execute SQL task, not a DFT: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14341/Using-the-Foreach-ADO-Enumerator-in-SSIS. Again this is _not_ the way you should be doing it though

Answer (score 2):

You need `Foreach` loop over `A` variable and SQL Task for your `TRUNCATE` and `INSERT` command. In SQL task you can simply add the parameter with `?` in your query like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customer Gender  Select Variable ?
```

and bind that parameter to you iterating current value in `Parameter Mapping` In left menu:[image: Parameter Mapping Menu]

Comment: This is what i was looking for. Thank you all for the help.